# BLE Battery Level Service doesn't read phone battery level

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments, nrf52

## My Setup

I'm using a `TI Launchpad` as a Bluetooth Low Energy Central Device, and my `Samsung Galaxy S21` as a Peripheral. I'm using `bTool` (for my launchpad) and `nRF Connect` (for the phone).

From `nRF Connect`, I'm making my phone advertise data, so that the Launchpad can connect to it (from `bTool`). Everything works fine until this point.

I used the **"Configure GATT Server"** option from `nRF Connect`, added a **Custom Service** and selected **Battery Level Service**. Also added a **Battery Level Characteristic**, with **"NOTIFY"** and **"READ"** permissions, that also includes two Descriptors: **Client Characteristic Configuration** and **Characteristic Presentation Format**.

## Expected Result

What I'm trying to do is, create a **Battery Level Service** (directly from the `nRF Connect` mobile app) that measures the battery level of my phone and sends it to my Launchpad.

The problem is, when opening `bTool`, I see that the battery level of my phone is not read. I can input some values by myself from the phone, but I would like the battery level of my phone to be read.

Also, I would like to be notified whenever the battery level has changed.

My question is: what did I do wrong? Does **Battery Level Service** actually take the battery information from the peripheral, or is it not intended for that?

## ** update **

This is the Battery Level service in my nRF Connect, together with its characteristics + permissions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqYeK.jpg

Also, this is my `bTool` log, where I display all of the peripheral's services and write `01:00` to the **Client Characteristic Configuration** descriptor:

```
[1] : <Tx> - 11:40:18.260
-Type           : 0x01 (Command)
-OpCode         : 0xFD84 (GATT_DiscAllCharDescs)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) byte(s)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 StartHandle    : 0x0001 (1)
 EndHandle      : 0xFFFF (65535)
Dump(Tx):
0000:01 84 FD 06 00 00 01 00 FF FF                   ..........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[2] : <Rx> - 11:40:18.290
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x067F (1663) (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 OpCode         : 0xFD84 (GATT_DiscAllCharDescs)
 DataLength     : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 06 7F 06 00 84 FD 00                      .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[3] : <Rx> - 11:40:18.411
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x17 (23) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0505 (1285) (ATT_FindInfoRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x11 (17)
 Format         : 0x01 (1) (HANDLE_BT_UUID_TYPE__handles_and_16_bit_Bluetooth_UUIDs)
 Handle         : 0001
 Uuid           : 00:28
 Handle         : 0014
 Uuid           : 00:28
 Handle         : 0028
 Uuid           : 00:28
 Handle         : 002F
 Uuid           : 00:28
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 17 05 05 00 00 00 11 01 01 00 00 28 14 00 .............(..
0010:00 28 28 00 00 28 2F 00 00 28                   .((..(/..(
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[4] : <Rx> - 11:40:18.610
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x0B (11) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0505 (1285) (ATT_FindInfoRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x05 (5)
 Format         : 0x01 (1) (HANDLE_BT_UUID_TYPE__handles_and_16_bit_Bluetooth_UUIDs)
 Handle         : 0030
 Uuid           : 03:28
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 0B 05 05 00 00 00 05 01 30 00 03 28       ..........0..(
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[5] : <Rx> - 11:40:18.798
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x0B (11) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0505 (1285) (ATT_FindInfoRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x05 (5)
 Format         : 0x01 (1) (HANDLE_BT_UUID_TYPE__handles_and_16_bit_Bluetooth_UUIDs)
 Handle         : 0031
 Uuid           : 19:2A
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 0B 05 05 00 00 00 05 01 31 00 19 2A       ..........1..*
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[6] : <Rx> - 11:40:19.004
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x0B (11) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0505 (1285) (ATT_FindInfoRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x05 (5)
 Format         : 0x01 (1) (HANDLE_BT_UUID_TYPE__handles_and_16_bit_Bluetooth_UUIDs)
 Handle         : 0032
 Uuid           : 02:29
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 0B 05 05 00 00 00 05 01 32 00 02 29       ..........2..)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[7] : <Rx> - 11:40:19.193
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0505 (1285) (ATT_FindInfoRsp)
 Status         : 0x1A (26) (bleProcedureComplete)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 06 05 05 1A 00 00 00                      .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[8] : <Tx> - 11:40:24.896
-Type           : 0x01 (Command)
-OpCode         : 0xFD92 (GATT_WriteCharValue)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) byte(s)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 Handle         : 0x0032 (50)
 Value          : 01:00
Dump(Tx):
0000:01 92 FD 06 00 00 32 00 01 00                   ......2...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[9] : <Rx> - 11:40:24.942
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x067F (1663) (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 OpCode         : 0xFD92 (GATT_WriteCharValue)
 DataLength     : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 06 7F 06 00 92 FD 00                      .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[10] : <Rx> - 11:40:25.085
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0513 (1299) (ATT_WriteRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 06 13 05 00 00 00 00                      .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### ** update (2) **

Log starting from `GATT_DiscAllPrimaryServices`:

```
[1] : <Tx> - 09:37:03.083
-Type           : 0x01 (Command)
-OpCode         : 0xFD90 (GATT_DiscAllPrimaryServices)
-Data Length    : 0x02 (2) byte(s)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
Dump(Tx):
0000:01 90 FD 02 00 00                               ......
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[2] : <Rx> - 09:37:03.113
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x067F (1663) (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 OpCode         : 0xFD90 (GATT_DiscAllPrimaryServices)
 DataLength     : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 06 7F 06 00 90 FD 00                      .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[3] : <Rx> - 09:37:03.249
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x13 (19) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0511 (1297) (ATT_ReadByGrpTypeRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x0D (13)
 Length         : 0x06 (6)
 DataList
 AttrHandle     : 0001
 EndGrpHandle   : 0003
 Value          : 01:18
 AttrHandle     : 0014
 EndGrpHandle   : 001A
 Value          : 00:18

Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 13 11 05 00 00 00 0D 06 01 00 03 00 01 18 ................
0010:14 00 1A 00 00 18                               ......
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[4] : <Rx> - 09:37:03.430
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x1B (27) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0511 (1297) (ATT_ReadByGrpTypeRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x15 (21)
 Length         : 0x14 (20)
 DataList
 AttrHandle     : 0028
 EndGrpHandle   : 002E
 Value          : 25:81:E8:8C:72:2E:8F:97:EA:11:DB:31:FC:34:4A:59
                  

Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 1B 11 05 00 00 00 15 14 28 00 2E 00 25 81 ..........(...%.
0010:E8 8C 72 2E 8F 97 EA 11 DB 31 FC 34 4A 59       ..r......1.4JY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[5] : <Rx> - 09:37:03.631
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x0D (13) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0511 (1297) (ATT_ReadByGrpTypeRsp)
 Status         : 0x00 (0) (SUCCESS)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x07 (7)
 Length         : 0x06 (6)
 DataList
 AttrHandle     : 002F
 EndGrpHandle   : FFFF
 Value          : 0F:18

Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 0D 11 05 00 00 00 07 06 2F 00 FF FF 0F 18 ........../.....
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[6] : <Rx> - 09:37:03.646
-Type           : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode      : 0x00FF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event          : 0x0511 (1297) (ATT_ReadByGrpTypeRsp)
 Status         : 0x1A (26) (bleProcedureComplete)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 PduLen         : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
0000:04 FF 06 11 05 1A 00 00 00                      .........
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "The problem is, when opening bTool, I see that the battery level of my phone is not read." -> This is not very clear. You need to subscribe to Battery Level Characteristic. How are you trying to accomplish this?

Comment: It seems like [this](http://software-dl.ti.com/lprf/simplelink_cc2640r2_sdk-1.50/docs/blestack/btool_user_guide/BTool_Users_Guide/index.html) is the tool. Can you add the picture of Read/Write section?

Comment: @Mr.Panda I'm setting the "Client Characteristic Configuration" value to `01:00` from bTool, 01:00 meaning "Enable notifications" (default value is `00:00`)

Comment: @Mr.Panda Updated the question with a screenshot + bTool's log

Comment: I wonder if nRF Connect is even capable of reading your phones battery status. I never tried it myself but maybe the battery service is actually just a service without any more logic behind it

Comment: I believe it [can](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/1.2.0/nrf/include/bluetooth/services/bas_c.html). Your @MarioMateas log seems pretty clear. No errors. However I am curious about this -> `Handle         : 0x0032 (50)` Can you include your log starting from `GATT_DiscAllPrimaryServices (0xFD90)`.

Comment: @Mr.Panda Done. Please check **Update (2)**

Comment: @MarioMateas where is the characteristic discovery? I meant the whole log.